# Parse file to hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm a ruby newcomer who's trying to read a text file (a Valgrind simulation output) like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Profile data file 'temp/gt_1024_2_16.out'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I1 cache:         1024 B, 16 B, 2-way associative
D1 cache:         32768 B, 64 B, 8-way associative
LL cache:         3145728 B, 64 B, 12-way associative
Profiled target:  bash run.sh
Events recorded:  Ir I1mr ILmr Dr D1mr DLmr Dw D1mw DLmw
Events shown:     Ir I1mr ILmr Dr D1mr DLmr Dw D1mw DLmw
Event sort order: Ir I1mr ILmr Dr D1mr DLmr Dw D1mw DLmw
Thresholds:       99 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Include dirs:     
User annotated:   
Auto-annotation:  off

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Ir    I1mr  ILmr      Dr  D1mr  DLmr      Dw  D1mw  DLmw 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1,894,017 246,981 2,448 519,124 4,691 2,792 337,817 1,846 1,672  PROGRAM TOTALS

// other data
```

I want to extract the PROGRAM TOTALS table and put it into a hash. Something like...

```
myHash = { :Ir => 1894017, :I1mr => 246981, ILmr => 2448, ..., DLmw => 1672 }
```

What are the best options for doing this? Could the CSV classes help me out? Thanks a bunch.

My current code:

```
file = File.open(fileName, "r")
while header = file.gets
  if header =~ /       Ir    I1mr  ILmr      Dr  D1mr  DLmr      Dw  D1mw  DLmw /
    # Found the header
    file.gets # skip the ---- line
    values = file.gets

    puts "Header: " + header
    puts "  Data: " + values
    break
  end
end
```

I've got this output:

```
Header:        Ir    I1mr  ILmr      Dr  D1mr  DLmr      Dw  D1mw  DLmw 
  Data: 1,894,017 246,981 2,448 519,124 4,691 2,792 337,817 1,846 1,672  PROGRAM TOTALS
```

How could I join these two strings into a hash?

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)" We need to see your effort in attempting to solve this. While you're just starting out, it's still important to know you're trying to solve this on your own, not expecting us to do it for you. CSV won't help really, because it's made for more structured data.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the tips. I've attached my current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at:

```
NAMES_INDEX = 16 # the line number of Ir I1mr ILmr Dr ... 
NUMBERS_INDEX = 18 # the line number of 1,894,017 246,981 2,448 ...
FILE_NAME= "temp/gt_1024_2_16.out" # the file name
f = f = File.readlines(FILE_NAME)
names = f[NAMES_INDEX].split
numbers = f[NUMBERS_INDEX].split[0..-3].map{|a| a.delete(",").to_i}

h = Hash[names.zip numbers]
p h
```

Comment: Perfect! And easy to understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: Instead of `f = File.open(FILE_NAME).readlines` use `f = File.readlines(FILE_NAME)`. The way you're doing it leaves the file open needlessly. Do that in a loop enough times and your code will crash because you'd consume all the available file handles on the system.

Comment: Instead of `a.gsub(",", "")` use `a.delete(',')`. `gsub` has a bit more overhead than `delete`. `'a,b,c'.delete(',') # => "abc"`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your column names are fixed, since you search for them to find the data line.

This is how I would do it

```
data = nil

names = %w/ Ir    I1mr  ILmr      Dr  D1mr  DLmr      Dw  D1mw  DLmw /

open('E:\Perl\source\valgrind.txt', 'r') do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    if line =~ /PROGRAM TOTALS/
      values = line.scan(/[\d\,]+/).map { |num| num.tr(',', '').to_i  }
      data = Hash[ names.zip(values) ]
      break
    end
  end
end

p data
```

**output**

```
{"Ir"=>1894017, "I1mr"=>246981, "ILmr"=>2448, "Dr"=>519124, "D1mr"=>4691, "DLmr"=>2792, "Dw"=>337817, "D1mw"=>1846, "DLmw"=>1672}
```

Comment: You can use `File.foreach()` to replace your `open` and `each_line` loops. It's cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I would write the code like this:

```
file_path, lines_with_data = 'data.txt', [16,18]
header, data = File.readlines(file_path)
                   .values_at(*lines_with_data)
                   .map{|line| line.strip.gsub(',','')
                   .split(/\s+/)}
data.map!(&:to_i)
p Hash[header.zip(data)] # => {"Ir"=>1894017, "I1mr"=>246981, "ILmr"=>2448, "Dr"=>519124, "D1mr"=>4691, "DLmr"=>2792, "Dw"=>337817, "D1mw"=>1846, "DLmw"=>1672}
```